# Python compare list to dictionary with multiple values and return matches

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension, key-value, key-value-coding

If I this list:

```py
list1 = ['a long way home she said', 'amazing grace for me', 'shes super cool']
```

I want to compare each item in list 1 to the values in dict1 below:

```py
dict1 = {
'Formula1': ('a long way home', 'nothing to see here'),
'Formula 2': ('nasty girl', 'nope'),
'Formula 3': ('disguisting', 'nope'),
'Formula 4': ('amazing grace', 'hello world')
}
```

How can I get the output to return the key from dict1 with the entire matching phrase in list1?

The desired output would be:

`['Formula1': ('a long way home she said'), 'Formula 4': ('amazing grace for me')] or`

`{'Formula1': ('a long way home she said'), 'Formula 4': ('amazing grace for me')}`

I was trying to do this like so:

`import itertools`

`[x if not x in itertools.chain(dict1.values()) else [key for key in dict1 if value in dict[key]][0] for x in list1]`

But I think my output is actually just going to return everything in the list after iterating through dictionary values. I have millions of records to go through so list comprehension is preferable to a loop.

`[name for name, title in dict1.items() if all(x in title for x in list1)]`

This just returned an empty list

Comment: If there's multiple phrases that match in `list1`, should the result contain all of them or only the first?

Comment: the result should contain all of the phrases that match in list1 @BrokenBenchmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each key in the dictionary, create a new tuple. For every element in `list1`, if there exists a string in the original tuple value that is a substring of that element, then retain it in the result. Store the result of this computation (in the below code snippet, we store it in the `phrases` variable).

Then, we filter out all of the key-value pairs that have empty tuples for values using a dictionary comprehension. You could condense this into one line, but I think it becomes pretty unreadable at that point:

```py
phrases = {
    key: tuple(
            filter(lambda x: any(substr in x for substr in value), list1)
        )
        for key, value in dict1.items()
}
result = {key: value for key, value in phrases.items() if value != ()}

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
{
    'Formula1': ('a long way home she said',),
    'Formula 4': ('amazing grace for me',)
}
```